# Three js appear line not perfect when rotation

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

I create a cube with 6 plane and using border for each plane with line. it seem ok but when i rotate object, line show very ugly sometime it not show. If i use WebGLRenderer, it work perfect but i must use  CanvasRenderer.

```js
 $(function(){
  var scene = new THREE.Scene();
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,0.1,10000);
  var renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer({alpha: true});
  renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 0);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
  var axes = new THREE.AxisHelper(20);
  scene.add(axes);

  var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(60,60);
  var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xcccccc,side: THREE.DoubleSide });
  var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry,planeMaterial);

  var object3D = new THREE.Object3D();
  plane.rotation.x = -0.5*Math.PI;
  plane.position.x = 0;
  plane.position.y = 0;
  plane.position.z = 0;

  var boder1 = drawBoder(plane);
  boder1.rotation.x = -0.5*Math.PI;
  object3D.add(boder1);
  object3D.add(plane);
  
  var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff00cc,side: THREE.DoubleSide});
  var plane2 = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry,planeMaterial);

  plane2.position.x = 0;
  plane2.position.y = 30;
  plane2.position.z = -30;

  var boder2 = drawBoder(plane2);
  boder2.position.x = 0;
  boder2.position.y = 30;
  boder2.position.z = -30;
  object3D.add(boder2);

  object3D.add(plane2);


  var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ffcc});
  var plane3 = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry,planeMaterial);

  plane3.position.x = 0;
  plane3.position.y = 30;
  plane3.position.z = 30;

  var boder3 = drawBoder(plane3);
  boder3.position.x = 0;
  boder3.position.y = 30;
  boder3.position.z = 30;
  object3D.add(boder3);

  object3D.add(plane3);


  var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xbbeecc,side: THREE.DoubleSide});
  var plane4 = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry,planeMaterial);

  plane4.rotation.y = 0.5*Math.PI;
  plane4.position.x = -30;
  plane4.position.y = 30;
  plane4.position.z = 0;

  var boder4 = drawBoder(plane4);
  boder4.rotation.y = 0.5*Math.PI;
  boder4.position.x = -30;
  boder4.position.y = 30;
  boder4.position.z = 0;
  object3D.add(boder4);

  object3D.add(plane4);

  var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xeebbee,side: THREE.DoubleSide});
  var plane5 = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry,planeMaterial);

  plane5.rotation.x = -0.5*Math.PI;
  plane5.position.x = 0;
  plane5.position.y = 60;
  plane5.position.z = 0;

  var boder5 = drawBoder(plane5);
  boder5.rotation.x = -0.5*Math.PI;
  boder5.position.x = 0;
  boder5.position.y = 60;
  boder5.position.z = 0;
  object3D.add(boder5);

  object3D.add(plane5);

  var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xccbbbb,side: THREE.DoubleSide});
  var plane6 = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry,planeMaterial);
  plane6.rotation.y = 0.5*Math.PI;
  plane6.position.x = 30;
  plane6.position.y = 30;
  plane6.position.z = 0;

  var boder6 = drawBoder(plane6);
  boder6.rotation.y = 0.5*Math.PI;
  boder6.position.x = 30;
  boder6.position.y = 30;
  boder6.position.z = 0;
  object3D.add(boder6);

  object3D.add(plane6);

  scene.add(object3D);

  camera.position.x = 600;
  camera.position.y = 500;
  camera.position.z = 200;
  camera.lookAt(scene.position);
  $("#webgl-output").append(renderer.domElement);

  render();
  
  function render(){
   renderer.render(scene,camera);
  }


  function drawBoder(plane){
                var materialLine = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
                    color: 0x231916,
                    linewidth: 2,
                });
                var geometryLine = new THREE.Geometry();
                geometryLine.vertices.push(
                    plane.geometry.vertices[0],
                    plane.geometry.vertices[1],
                    plane.geometry.vertices[1],
                    plane.geometry.vertices[3],
                    plane.geometry.vertices[2],
                    plane.geometry.vertices[0]
                );
            var lineBorder = new THREE.Line( geometryLine, materialLine );
            return lineBorder;


  }

  $("#btnLeft").click(function(){
   object3D.rotation.y += 0.1;
   render();
  });

  $("#btnRight").click(function(){
   object3D.rotation.y -= 0.1;
   render();
  });
  $("#btnUp").click(function(){
   object3D.rotation.z += 0.1;
   render();
  });

  $("#btnDown").click(function(){
   object3D.rotation.z -= 0.1;
   render();
  });
 });
```

```html
<div id="webgl-output">
 
</div>
<button id="btnLeft">left</button>
<button id="btnRight">right</button>
<button id="btnUp">Up</button>
<button id="btnDown">Down</button>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r61/three.min.js"></script>
```